# How to read scanned table in Python using pytesseract?

Tags: python, dataframe, image-processing

I'm trying to read data tables from an image file with pytesseract. My image is that one:
[p27-001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5OYl.jpg)

Initially I tried to use the image_to_data method:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

tab_im = Image.open('p27-001.jpg')
tab = pytesseract.image_to_data(tab_im)
print(tab)
```

but I always get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tess_3se80zvv_out.tsv
```

So I decided to use the image_to_boxes method. To be sure I do not quite understand what this method does, but I got the following ouput:

```
X 119 1339 132 1351 0

X 134 1340 146 1351 0

~ 120 1328 305 1332 0

~ 306 1328 384 1332 0

~ 385 1328 508 1332 0

D 296 1339 308 1351 0

I 310 1339 316 1351 0

R 318 1339 329 1351 0

E 331 1338 342 1351 0

C 344 1338 353 1352 0

’ 355 1346 357 1351 0

I 358 1339 363 1351 0

‘ 363 1347 366 1351 0

... continue
```

Anyone knows what it means? Is there another way to read this table in python?

My intention is transform these data in a csv file.

Comment: the obvious way would be to first find out what functions do befor you complain about any errors using them. enter "tesseract box" and find https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract-%E2%80%93-Make-Box-Files. The output is a box file which is used to train Tesseract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: [Training Tesseract – Make Box Files](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Training-Tesseract-%E2%80%93-Make-Box-Files)

character, left, bottom, right, top, page

So for each character you get the character, followed by its bounding box characters, followed by the 0-based page number.

These files are created and used for training Tesseract. There are box file editors to view and edit them. For each training image you create a box file where you manually correct errors, Tesseract made.